# Consequences to setting the db compatibility level to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, compatibility-level

We have a Sql Server 2005 DB.  For whatever reason, the compatibility level (e.g. via sp_dbcmptlevel) is set to 80 (which is Sql Server 2000).

What are the consequences of that?  Is there a performance penalty for my apps because of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps: [Does running a SQL Server 2005 database in compatibility level 80 have a negative impact on performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237/does-running-a-sql-server-2005-database-in-compatibility-level-80-have-a-negative)

Edit: Not mentioned in the other thread, I think this one is quite interesting as well: http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/49643/sql_server_49643.html